# React Native Pie Chart - Want to show image (Victory Native)

Tags: javascript, react-native, charts, victory-charts, victory-native

I am adding a [Victory native Pie chart](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-pie/#standalone) in react native with some additional information to show within it. I am able to show different colors in the pie chart and able to show labels in it.

But what I want is - I want to show images also in Pie chart. Is there any workaround in it or some alternate way by which I can do it?

[image]